# Registration Form vba sql

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

maybe someone can help me with this code for a registration form using access.

```
Private Sub Befehl17_Click()
Dim sql As String
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
sql = "Select Username from dbo_UserTest1 where Username = '" & Me.Username & "' "
On Error GoTo weiter
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(sql)
If rs!Username= Null Then
weiter:
DoCmd.RunSQL "Insert Into dbo_UserTest1 (Username, Passwort) values ('" & Me.Username & "' , '" & Me.Passwort & "')"
Else
message = MsgBox("Name schon vorhanden", vbOKOnly)
End If
End Sub
```

It looks fine to me, but it didnt work at all. 
What did I do wrong?

Comment: Never store passwords as flat-text!

Comment: I assign the text field as a "password" format.

Comment: Null values should be checked using the `IsNull()` function. `If IsNull(rs!Username) ...`

Comment: Kostas K. that is a good point!
haha, to avoid the error message i set the Warnings to false.

Comment: You shouldn't turn Warnings to False but handle the error(s). :)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I got it. 
Not my vba+sql code was wrong my database table was wrong.

Thx for your help.